When i tried to add the third well known node, it shows is added but it's not?
I am following the Authorize Specific Nodes and i tried to add the third known node, but i couldn't. It said it was added but it seems it did not even though i tried to added again it said it is already added


I´ve changed the format of the Genesis Config adapting it to the node template format, and when i check it did not show any error, so i think that is not the error.
And my error:
Report 12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2: -2147483648 to -2147483648. Reason: Genesis mismatch. Banned, disconnecting.


In my repo is the chain.spec:  https://github.com/NXHM/blockchain-permisionada
When i added to the quesiton, was marked as spamm

how did you launch your other nodes? genesis mismatch happens when the node doesn't use the same chain spec that the network was launched with

I used this commands:
./target/release/node-template --chain=local --base-path /tmp/validator2 --bob --node-key=6ce3be907dbcabf20a9a5a60a712b4256a54196000a8ed4050d352bc113f8c58 --bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2 --port 30334 --rpc-port 9945
./target/release/node-template --chain=local --base-path /tmp/validator3 --name charlie  --node-key=3a9d5b35b9fb4c42aafadeca046f6bf56107bd2579687f069b42646684b94d9e --port 30335 --rpc-port=9946 --offchain-worker always

i fixed it erasing all the validators and repeat the same steps. This time i added the third node while it was trying to connect to the blockchain and it worked. I guess it should worked even if i shutted down the blockchain and i tried to connect the blockchain via the third node
